# Array output format in php

Tags: php

I am running SQL select query,getting the result in below format after executing the query.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [usertype_id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [usertype_id] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [usertype_id] => 17
        )

)
```

But i need result in below format

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 17
)
```

So how to loop through this to get the output in above format.

Comment: What you have tried? can you post some code here

Comment: [array_column](http://php.net/array_column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array `array_map()`

```
$res= array_map(function($arr=array()){
    return $arr['usertype_id'];
},$input);
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) works just fine here:

https://3v4l.org/qX46k

```
<?php

$input = [['usertype_id' => 14], ['usertype_id' => 15], ['usertype_id' => 17]];
$expected = [14,15,17];

$result = array_column($input, 'usertype_id');

var_dump($result === $expected);
```

**Output for 7.1.25 - 7.3.2**

> bool(true)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO, then you can do as below

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT usertype_id FROM user");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the values of the first column */
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
print_r($result);
?>
```

> **Reference:** http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @Xatenev *I am running SQL select query*... Perhaps?

Comment: Please look at the question first, he clearly written "I am running SQL select query,getting the result in below format after executing the query."

Comment: @SomnathSinha Right... my bad :/. Sadly stackoverflow decides I can't change my vote anymore without you editing your answer.